# How to convert Express errors into user-friendly message?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, middleware

I am new to coding and learning Node/Express and trying to process MongoDB errors into user-friendly messages.

I read a similar article on here but it dealt with sanitizing data in mongoose schema before querying MongoDB.

In Postman, I get the below error after intentionally creating an account (I am using Mongoose) with a username already in use, in this case 'johnsmith'.

Instead of this error object I would like to send back "username already exists" OR "email already in use" depending on the error.

Is there straight forward use of middleware than can accomplish this?

Thank you!

```
{
// Json error
    "driver": true,
    "name": "MongoError",
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "keyPattern": {
        "username": 1
    },
    "keyValue": {
        "username": "johnsmith"
    }
}
```

```
// Express Code

router.post(`/api/user/create`, async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const user = await new User(req.body)
    
    try {
        await user.save()
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()
        res.status(201).send({user, token})
    } catch (err) {
     
        res.status(400).send(err) 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you would want to use a middleware here. I also don't think there is a middleware that can 'automagically' do that for you.
You can always write your own middleware BTW.

But in your specific case I would handle that problem right there where you want to create the new user. A middleware would only make sense when you want to deal with something on multiple routes.

Thus I would simply handle that problem right where you catch the error.
You already know how the error delivered by mongoose looks like when the username already exists, so you can test for that case, e.g.:

```js
} catch(err) {
    if(err.name === "MongoError" && "keyValue" in err && "username" in err.keyValue) {
       return res.status(409).send({message: "User already exists"})
    }
    else {
      return res.status(500).send(err)
    }
}
```